# How to set the current site collection path in an "a href" in Display Template?

Tags: display-template

I am building a display template. There is a control template and a item template. In the item template I have some a href tag. In this a href tag I would like to link to some page inside the current site collection. How can I implement this?

This is not working:

```
var Body = '<table id="StandPuntTable">' +
            '<tr><td>' + Bestuurder + '</td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td><H1>' + Title + '</H1></td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td><img src="/sites/khha/_catalogs/masterpage/test/images/tag-underline.png" /></div></td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td>' + IntroText + '<br></br></td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td><a href="/Pages/Standpunt-detail-lijst.aspx?standpuntID=' + ListItemID + '" class="leesMeer"><img src="/sites/khha/_catalogs/masterpage/test/images/lees-meer.png" />Lees de volledige toelichting</a></td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td><a href="/Pages/Standpunt-detail-lijst.aspx" class="button-right">Alle onze standpunten op een rij</a></td></tr>' +
            '</table>';
```

The link is going to the root site collection, but I have also sub site collections. So I would like to refer to this page in the current site collection.

Answer (score 1):

How about the classic double dot?

```
../Pages/Standpunt-detail-lijst.aspx
```

Taking away the Pages part of the current page and then appends your string.

Comment: If I use the 2 dots it is still refering to the root site collection "http://myCompany.com/Pages/Standpunt-detail-lijst.aspx". But it needs to stay in the current site collection, for example "http://myCompany.com/sites/khha/Pages/Standpunt-detail-lijst.aspx"

Comment: Is the link really placed in the subsite?

Comment: not a subsite. It is a site collection with the url "http://myCompany.com/sites/khha"

Comment: If that is the URL you should just write "Pages/" and so on

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution: `var currentSiteCollectionFullUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;`